# Testing a PID controller, need equation for PV

Tags: simulation, pid-controller, testing

I am writing a basic PID controller for the purposes of a completely in-computer simulation, no hardware to run it on. I only the PID. How can I test it on some simulated physical environment? I have seen some examples in [this course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLciAw3uhNCiD3dkLTPJgHoMnsu8XgCt1m) years ago.

I need an equation to compute the process variable  in response to controller output, for some fake system.

```
PV(t,u) = ?
```

Comment: I used PID for a game in Scratch. A mouse, controlled by a player was escaping a cat that followed it by PID.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're expecting us to tell you, but:

Invent an example physical system, with a simulated behaviour, and test that.

Idea from the first hour of my Control Systems lecture back in the day:

PID controller that monitors the fill level of a bath tub, adjusts the inlet, and works against a leaky outlet would be an easy-to-simulate system.

Writing simulations requires more understanding than just writing a controller that works within, so I'm afraid: Since you didn't tell us which languages/frameworks you're working with, we'll have to assume that you'll need to write a simulator, and that means you'll have to understand the numerical and bandwidth needs of a simulator before you can tackle this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for any dynamics for your simulator, I would suggest using the 1D equations of motion of a brick on a (low friction) inclined plane, where the manipulated variable is the force on the brick. Proportional controller will give some oscillation, derivative will add damping, and integrator will help null out steady state error due to gravity.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Marcus, a bath tub system. PID controls the inlet and measures the level of water, and adjusts to obtain and sustain a setpoint amount of water.

```
init:
  PV = 0
update:
  PV += 5*u*dt - 0.01*PV
```